# How do I add an integer to an integer ArrayList in a GUI?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I am trying to add the Integer inputted by the user to the `ArrayList`. It's originally a `String`, so I converted it to an `Integer`. I added the `Integer` to the `Arraylist`, but now I'm not sure how to display it. I want to be able to keep adding marks, and have all the marks displayed on the screen. I tried a for loop, but I'm not sure what the second parameter would be.

Edit: `for (i=0; ... ; i++)` -- What would go in the second place?

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    String strInputMark;
    int intInputMark;

    strInputMark = txtInputMark.getText();
    intInputMark = Integer.parseInt(strInputMark);

    ArrayList<Integer> Marks = new ArrayList<>();

    int intMarks;
    Marks.add(intInputMark);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the GUI part of your code? All I see is an ArrayList with Integer values...

Comment: What do you mean by second parameter ? what did you tried

Comment: I added the GUI part, if that helps! By second parameter, I meant the second part of the for loop.

Comment: What GUI part exactly?

Comment: A good programming practice is to have the variable name begin with a lower case letter, in your case, `marks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for loop:

```
String output = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < Marks.size(); i++){
        output += "\n"+Marks.get(i);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String strInputMark;
Integer intInputMark;

strInputMark = txtInputMark.getText();
intInputMark = Integer.valueOf(strInputMark);

ArrayList<Integer> Marks = new ArrayList <>();

int intMarks;
Marks.add(intInputMark);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `i < Marks.size()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < Marks.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(Marks.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is two-fold.  First, you need to move 'Marks' outside of the method scope so it can be accessible and continually appended two as input continues.  Second, as @Umesh said, Marks.size() will give you the total number of elements in your arraylist.